# Factorial - unresolved compilation, must return a result of type int

Tags: java, factorial

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial
{
    public int factorial(int n)
    {   if(n==1)
        {   
        return 1;
        }

        while(n>1)
        {
            return(n*factorial(n-1));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   int fact=1;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number:");
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        Factorial f=new Factorial();
        fact=f.factorial(n);
        System.out.println("Factorial is:"+fact);

    }
}
```

//output:

```
Enter Number:
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type int

    at Factorial.factorial(Factorial.java:5)
    at Factorial.main(Factorial.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are not all covered by return;

```
while(n>1)
{
    return(n*factorial(n-1));
}
return 1; // Add this
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: all paths need to return. You do not have a return after the while loop.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int factorial(int n) {
    if(n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question 
After `while (n > 1)` technically should be a `return` command.

That's why you have a compilation error. But you can simplify your code reducing unnecessary `while(...)` operation. Look at Hemant Patel answer.